# how to open link in a new window and set size after page load?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, window, pageload

I have a link with querystring like **"...com/default3.aspx?id=123?code=456"** This link create automatically and sending in mail as a hyperlink. I design default3.aspx page and doing some operations according to querystring. Is that a way open this link in a new window and set window size, after clicked from mail this link?

I tried this but it doesn't work.

```
<body onload="resizeWindow()" >
...
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function resizeWindow() 
   {           
    // you can get height and width from serverside as well      
    var width=100;
    var height=100; 
    window.resizeTo(width,height);           
    }
    </script>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to open window using window.open like **window.open("", "", "width=200, height=100");**

Check out sample code at W3Schools **http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp**

Check for demo using **Try it yourself**

Answer (score 0):

I think You should use this javascript function as i have used the same code in many of my webforms and it is also tested.

window.open('Redirecturl.aspx','Graph','height=600,width=800,resizable=yes');